# In a school library I have 30 iPads to set up for teachers to use in their classrooms.

Tags: ipad, apple-id

In a school library with 30 iPads on a cart.  Should one appleid be used for all 30 iPads?  I will be the only one adding the apps, and then the cart will be taken to classrooms.  The same apps will be on all iPads.  Would it be better to just create a genric appleid or an iCloud id, or what's the best way to do this?

Comment: look at [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12)

Comment: Jason, you should expand on this a bit and make it an answer.

Comment: This isn't a simple question--and it may be a debate.  Different institutions have different answers based on their requirements and licensing. Entire conference tracks have been devoted to this topic. You might find the writings of [Fraser Speirs] and [iPad Mike](http://ipadmike.tumblr.com/post/40535136879/ipad-apps-and-resources-for-teachers) to be helpful. There is also a lot of information about MDM at [JAMFnation](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/index.html)

Comment: Forgot to add the link for [Fraser Speirs](http://speirs.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a tool, [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12), designed to help manage multiple devices in exactly this kind of scenario.  I haven't personally used it, but it sound like what you need.

Answer (score 3):

No - if you try to use one Apple ID on more than 10 devices without some sort of management software layer, you will end up getting that account locked. It's better to reach out to Apple (or a consultant) that does this to learn the benefits and drawbacks of managing a cart of devices.

If you wanted to ask a more specific follow on question or edit some details to make your situation a little more narrow (where in the world your deployment is based, what you've tried to solve the issue, etc..) it's hard to offer anything other than links to places to start doing research:

- http://www.apple.com/education/resources/information-technology.html

The link above has videos explaining various enrollment strategies, how to use the configurator, white papers, volume purchase information (which means educational discounts) and more.

Answer (score 2):

For our iPad distros we are using two accounts:one [Volume Purchasing Program account](https://volume.itunes.apple.com/us/store) and one regular apple ID and [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12).

Example: ipadcartVPP@company.com buys the VPP app codes from apple and I download the excel sheet with the redemption codes. Then I would redeem one of the codes on ipadcart@company.com to download the .ipa file. That .ipa file gets loaded into Configurator along with the excel sheet with all the codes(their basic license mgmt) and allows you to apply the profile(Prefs and Apps) to managed devices.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this..product

http://www.maas360.com/

MaaS360 provides a mobile device management solution and an enterprise appstore for managing apps

DISCLOSURE: This author is affiliated with this product.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Apple ID in all those 30 devices. Instead, there are two ways in which you can achieve it.

The first method is using [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205285). Apple Configurator is a tool that is available in Mac computers. With Apple Configurator, you can download apps from iTunes and can be deployed in devices if by hooking up the device with your Mac computer and deploying apps one by one.

If this sounds annoying, then there is a second option called [Mobile Application Management (MAM)](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-application-management/). Enroll all the 30 devices in MAM and you can deploy apps remotely from another system.

Some [Mobile Device Management (MDM)](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-device-management-software/) solutions, like [Hexnode MDM](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/), also comes with a built-in MAM. MDM provides more options of security like locking device and wiping it down, just in case you need it.